# Primefaces with Highchart error in second time

Tags: jsf, primefaces, highcharts

In my college project I migrating RichFaces to PrimeFaces 5.1. In main page left navigation link press to include student page. In student page to press  searchButton , 3d chart to shown.It's work fine.My problem is user mistakingly again press student navigation link that time highchart is not shown(highchart to be empty).

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
<h:form id="test" binding="#{stud.initForm}>
<p:outputPanel id="testPanel">
<p:commandButton value="Search' action="#{stud.searchAction}" update="testPanel"/>
<div id="pieChartdata"> </div>

</p:outputPanel>
</h:form>
```

Comment: what is the error in error console? check browser error console

Comment: There is a syntax error in `<p:commandButton>`. Check for any error / exception on both client and server sides.

Comment: @ Nishith Kant Chaturvedi I check browser error console no error.I face problem at a time to click same navigation. When refresh page its works fine